# Two different routes using the same child components are evaluating data differently

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-router4

Using Vue3 and vue-router4, two different components share the same child components. The component templates are setup as follows:

```html
<!-- Component A -->
<template>
  <ComponentA>
    <Child />
  </ComponentA>
</template>

<!-- Component B -->
<template>
  <ComponentB>
    <Child />
  </ComponentB>
</template>

<!-- Child -->
<template>
  <FilterResults />
</template>
```

These are the configured routes:

```js
const routes = [
    {
        path:'/componenta/:param',
        component: ComponentA
    },
    {
        path:'/componentb',
        component: ComponentB
    }
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
})
```

Some data is setup in the `Child` component:

```js
export default {
  name: 'Child'
  ...,
  data() {
    return {
      filters: {
        size: [
          {
            selected: this.$route.query.size === "1m"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above aims to set `selected` to true or false depending on whether a match is found in the route. The results is then passed into `FilterResults` as a prop:

```html
<!-- Component A -->
<template>
  <ComponentA>
    <Child />
  </ComponentA>
</template>

<!-- Component B -->
<template>
  <ComponentB>
    <Child />
  </ComponentB>
</template>

<!-- Child -->
<template>
  <FilterResults :filters="filters" />
</template>
```

With the above, the value of `selected` in the filter data is evaluated and the intended result is that when the components load, the filters in the $route are set to `true` in the data.

The problem is, where the child components of `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` are identical:

- `ComponentA` `/componenta/xyz?size=1m` **does not** work as intended, where matches found in the route **are not** set to `true` in the `filters` data.
- `ComponentB` `/componentb?size=1m` **does** work as intended, where matches found in the route **are** set to `true` in the `filters` data.

Comment: Can you show how your URL is when you visit the page of component A?

Comment: Sure. ComponentA url is https://exampledomain.com/componenta/xyz?size=1m and does not work. Component B url is https://exampledomain.com/componentb?size=1m and this does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem only if `router-view` isn't keyed, so I'm assuming that's what you have.

If there are two `router-link`s to the same component but with different `size` query parameters (as shown below), and you're clicking one link and then the other, Vue reuses the existing component instance, so the component's `data()` is not invoked, and the query parameter is not re-evaluated.

```html
<router-link to="/componenta/xyz?size=1m">A (size=1m)</router-link> |
<router-link to="/componenta/xyz?size=0">A (size=0)</router-link> |
```

To ensure a new component is created for each route change, specify a `router-view` [key](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/special-attributes.html#key) on [`$route.fullPath`](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#fullpath) (which includes the query parameters):

```html
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/troubleshooting-route-query-processing-24qgd?file=/src/App.vue:312-362)

Comment: This fixed the issue. My router-views were not keyed. For my specific project, `:key="$route.path"` on the router-views got it working correctly for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the problem is here, your data is not recalculating on route change,
try to modify local data on route change. Try to add debugger before return statement in data, it will come only one even if change the route.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right cause as if I navigate directly the ComponentB route, it works, but if I navigate directly to the ComponentA route it does not work - So no route change has occured.